# MySQL order by number of occuring columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
|   id  |   name    |
----------------------
|   A   |   test a1 |
|   A   |   test a2 |
|   A   |   test a3 |
|   B   |   test b1 |
|   B   |   test b2 |
|   A   |   test a4 |
|   C   |   test c1 |
```

Id `A` has the most values, then `B`, etc. How can I return rows ordered by number of names that is associated with `id`. I tried this but since I group by `id` I lose all `names` that are associated with the `id`.

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(name) as name_count 
FROM users 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY name_count DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT t.* FROM users t JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM users GROUP BY id) s ON t.id = s.id ORDER BY c.cnt DESC`

Comment: Please add the desired result to your question.

Comment: A bit overkill for this case, but does MySQL still not have `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`? Gah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. To get around losing the names, you need to join a subquery to handle the counting:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u
JOIN (
  SELECT id, count(1) cnt
  FROM users
  GROUP BY id) ss 
ON u.id = ss.id
ORDER BY ss.cnt DESC
```

The subquery results in this

```
+----+-----+
| id | cnt |
+----+-----+
| A  |   4 |
| B  |   2 |
| C  |   1 |
+----+-----+
```

Joined to your original table we have these rows:

```
+------+---------+-------+--------+
| u.id | u.name  | ss.id | ss.cnt |
+------+---------+-------+--------+
| A    | test a1 | A     |      4 |
| A    | test a2 | A     |      4 |
| A    | test a3 | A     |      4 |
| B    | test b1 | B     |      2 |
| B    | test b2 | B     |      2 |
| A    | test a4 | A     |      4 |
| C    | test c1 | C     |      1 |
+------+---------+-------+--------+
```

So we only want to return the columns from the `u` users table and sort by the subquery's `ss.cnt`. You can select `u.*` though it's generally better practice to be explicit in the columns you want your query to return.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/738037/1)

You can also add sorting based on `u.name` if you want to sort your results within the ID groups:

`ORDER BY ss.cnt DESC, u.name`

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/738037/2)

Comment: @John You may also want to order on ID, probably before name, to make sure you group properly in the case of ties. If there was one more C, the cnt for both would be 2, so your order should be `ORDER BY ss.cnt DESC, u.id, u.name`

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved even without subquery if there is one column that is unique in `users` table. For example, if `name` is unique then it will be as follows:

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.name, COUNT(*) as name_count 
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON u1.id = u2.id
GROUP BY u1.name
ORDER BY name_count DESC
```